# join tables after group_by

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr

I want to perform a join on two tables after a group_by operation.

```
A <- data.frame(x1=c("a","b","c","d"))
B <- data.frame(x1=c("a","c","d","c","a"), x2=c(1,1,1,2,2))
```

The idea is that x2 is an ID, x1 may be something like a date and there may be other columns for values of temperatures. Table `A` contains all dates and `B` contains actual obervations. I would like to end up with a table with all dates for all IDs with NAs when there is no observation.
The folowwing command generates:

```
> dplyr::left_join(A,B,by="x1")
  x1 x2
1  a  1
2  a  2
3  b NA
4  c  1
5  c  2
6  d  1
```

But I would like something that is more like:

```
x1 x2
a  1
a  2
b NA
b NA
c  1
c  2
d  1
d NA
```

So I tried this without success:

```
B %>% dplyr::group_by(x2) %>% dplyr::left_join(A,.data,by="x1")
```

Keeping the `group_by(x2)` would really come in handy for me if possible

Comment: For your idea it could be right just a `merge(A, B, all = TRUE)` but the output would not fit into yours. Like @DavidArenburg I do not understand it too.

Comment: Just a note regarding the `group_by`-approach: `Groups are ignored for the purpose of joining, but the result preserves the grouping of x.` (from the help file `?left_join`)

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to add a variable that counts the number of observations of `x1` and then to complete the data.frame with `tidyr::complete`.

```
require(dplyr)

left_join(A, B, by="x1")  %>% 
  # add variable "obs"
  group_by(x1) %>%
  mutate(obs = seq(n())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  # complete the data
  tidyr::complete(x1, obs) %>%
  select(-obs)
```

Source: local data frame [8 x 2]

```
##      x1    x2
##   (chr) (dbl)
## 1     a     1
## 2     a     2
## 3     b    NA
## 4     b    NA
## 5     c     1
## 6     c     2
## 7     d     1
## 8     d    NA
```

Comment: I also checked if it worked adding a third column of values and it works. thanks very ingenious solution!

Comment: Hi again, I realized that it would come really handy for me to keep the following format `B %>% dplyr::group_by(x2) %>% dplyr::left_join(A,.data,by="x1")` . Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. First you want to join the two data sets by `x1` and then expand the data set according to the number of unique groups. Here's a possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
# Store the number of unique ids in x2
GRPs <- uniqueN(B$x2) 
# First join by x1 and then expand according to number of unique groups in x2
setDT(B)[A, .SD[c(1:.N, rep(NA, GRPs - .N))], by = x1, on = "x1"] 
#    x1 x2
# 1:  a  1
# 2:  a  2
# 3:  b NA
# 4:  b NA
# 5:  c  1
# 6:  c  2
# 7:  d  1
# 8:  d NA
```

Or a more specific solution to your specific case which could be a bit faster

```
setDT(B)[A, if(.N < GRPs) c(x2, rep(NA, GRPs - .N)) else x2, by = x1, on = "x1"]
```

---

Or per @Aruns comment, you could first *cross join* over unique values in `x1` in data `A` and in `x2` in data `B` and then update with `NA`s while performing an *anti join* over data set `B`

```
CJ(x1 = A$x1, x2 = B$x2, unique = TRUE)[!B, x2 := NA, on = c("x1", "x2")][]
```